# Duplicated rows must be unique

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, awk, unique

My file content is as following. I want to first columns values' sum. But 5th columns are not unique and it has not got every second. It should be unique and if there is no any second it is not important. Important that is UNIQUE.

```
 18 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:34 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:37 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:38 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:39 PM EEST
 18 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:40 PM EEST
 12 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:41 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:42 PM EEST
 18 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:43 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:44 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:45 PM EEST
 18 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:43 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:44 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:45 PM EEST
 12 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:46 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:47 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:48 PM EEST
 17 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:49 PM EEST
 12 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:50 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:51 PM EEST
  9 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:54 PM EEST
  9 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:55 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:56 PM EEST
 12 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:57 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:58 PM EEST
  7 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:59 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:00 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:01 PM EEST
  9 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:55 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:56 PM EEST
 12 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:57 PM EEST
 11 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:58 PM EEST
  7 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:37:59 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:00 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:01 PM EEST
 10 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:02 PM EEST
 15 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:03 PM EEST
 13 /traffic-2.log00980-####<Aug 7, 2016 11:38:04 PM EEST
```

Comment: please [edit] to show your attempts and also provide a [mcve]. Good also to read [ask].

Comment: also, what should be the output for the given example? and which is the 5th column here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by awk;

```
awk  '!seen[$5]++' yourFile | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

-first awk delete duplicate on 5th columns

-second is sum of the first fields.

Comment: teşekkür ederim :)

Comment: İşinize yaradı ise ne mutlu, upvote de kullanabilir misiniz. İyi çalışmalar.

Comment: 8-10 satırlık bir dosyada denedim dogru sonuç verdi yalnız 153.965 satırlık bir dosyada denedim sonucu linuxte 569.428 verirken aynı dosyayı excel de denedigimde sonucu 2.918.591 verdi

Comment: awk  '!seen[$5]++' yourFile | awk  '{print $5" "$1}' | sort -n  dediğinizde zamana göre sıralama yapacaktır, excel dede zamana göre sıralama yaparak ikisini kıyaslamayı deneyebilir misiniz, böylelikle neden kaynaklandığını bulma ihtimaliniz var.

Comment: Bu hesabı yeni açtım oy veremiyorum maalesef :( tyamak@hotmail.com a mail atabilir misiniz rica etsem?

Comment: Hocam merhaba tekrar email adresini yazarsan ordan yazışalım mümkünse?